# Load Data Infile All Skips Lines

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the Load Data Infile feature on MySQL and all of my lines are skipped. I have tried all solutions from other threads but can't find the one that fixes my issue. What is it that I am doing wrong that MySQL continues skip all of my lines?

**Query**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Stockton\\DataFiles\\emaimport.csv' INTO TABLE moving_average
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1, @col2, @col3) set ma_symbol=@col1,ma_date=@col2,ma15=@col3;
```

Table Structure (Only inserting into column ma15)

```
CREATE TABLE `moving_average` (
  `ma_symbol` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ma_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ma5` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma15` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma25` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma35` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma40` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma45` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma100` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ma_symbol`,`ma_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_symbol_moving_average` FOREIGN KEY (`ma_symbol`) REFERENCES `company` (`symbol`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Example of Data Being Entered**

```
TR,2016-02-18,29.919117000
TR,2016-02-19,30.045367375
TR,2016-02-22,29.994117375
TR,2016-02-23,30.015367125
TRC,2011-02-15,26.705000000
TRC,2011-02-16,26.777500125
TRC,2011-02-17,26.757499750
TRC,2011-02-18,26.758750000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs a [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for the `date` field.

Like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Stockton\\DataFiles\\emaimport.csv' INTO TABLE moving_average
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1, @col2, @col3) set ma_symbol=@col1,ma_date=STR_TO_DATE(@col2,'%Y-%m-%d'),ma15=@col3;
```

Comment: This still skipped all rows.

Comment: @Fenriqe Duggledorf: Also your example of data doesn't have data in string format. It should be: `'TR', '2016-02-18', 29.919117000`